# Accessing 2th element in varray column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, varray

Let's say a have a table with a varray column, defined as follow:

```
create or replace TYPE VARRAY_NUMBER_LIST AS VARRAY(15) OF NUMBER;
```

Now, I'm trying to select the first element of each varray column of my table. It works fine:

```
select (select * from table(myvarraycolumn) where rownum = 1) from mytable cc
```

It is returning an output like:

```
2
1
4
4
2
2
```

My issue occurs when I try to get the second element of each varray column with this SQL:

```
select (select * from table(myvarraycolumn) where rownum = 2) from mytable cc
```

In this case, all output lines are returning null. Please, let me know if I'm forgetting something or making some confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select rows 1 and 2 and then work out a way to filter out the unwanted preceding rows - one way is to use aggregation with a `CASE` statement to only match the second row:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4af00/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( myvarraycolumn ) AS
  SELECT SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 3 ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 4, 5, 6 ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT MAX( CASE ROWNUM WHEN 2 THEN COLUMN_VALUE END )
         FROM   TABLE( t.myvarraycolumn )
         WHERE  ROWNUM <= 2
       ) AS second_element
FROM   mytable t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4af00/1/0)**:

```
| SECOND_ELEMENT |
|----------------|
|              2 |
|              5 |
```

> My issue occurs when I try to get the second element of each varray column with this SQL:
>
> ```
> select (select * from table(myvarraycolumn) where rownum = 2) from mytable cc
> ```
>
> In this case, all output lines are returning null. Please, let me know if I'm forgetting something or making some confusion.

It is not working because: for the first row in the correlated inner query, `ROWNUM` is `1` and your filter is `WHERE ROWNUM = 2` then this reduces to `WHERE 1=2` and the filter is not matched and the row is discarded. The subsequent row will then be tested against a `ROWNUM` of `1` (since the previous row is no longer in the output and will not have a row number), which will again fail the test and be discarded. Repeat, ad nauseum and all rows fail the `WHERE` filter and are discarded.